# ng-repeat from for loop in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

here is my issue, i want to display the number of ticket for every user but it only display the last value. I want to display between every name of user his number of tickets he got.

Controller.js:

```
angular.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'dropdown', 'userdisplay', 'displayfilter',
  function($scope, dropdown, userdisplay, displayfilter) {

    $scope.test = "coucou";
    $scope.displaycompany = function() {
      var token = "xxxxxxx";
      dropdown.send(token).then(function(data) {

        $scope.usertab = data.organizations;
        console.log($scope.usertab);


      });

    }

    $scope.displayuser = function(id) {
      var token = "xxxxxxxxx";
      userdisplay
        .send(token, id)
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $scope.userbyorga = data.users;
          console.log(data.users);
          for (i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {

            var userid = data.users;


            var userarray = JSON.stringify(userid);
            localStorage.setItem("myid", userarray);
          }
        })

      .then(function() {
        var tabuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myid"));
        console.log(tabuser);
        for (i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++) {
          console.log(tabuser[i].id);
          displayfilter
            .user(token, tabuser[i].id)
            .then(function(data) {

              console.log(data.tickets.length);
              $scope.numtickets = data.tickets;
            })
        }

      })

    };
  }
])
```

And here is my view:

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
  <button ng-click="displaycompany()" id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                Entreprises <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
    <li ng-repeat="item in usertab track by $index" ng-click="displayuser(item.id)">{{item.name}}</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<ul ng-repeat="user in userbyorga track by $index">{{user.name}}
  <li>{{numtickets.length}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here what i get in my console: [image]

Comment: I think in the `for` loop you meant `var userid = data.users[i];` instead of var `userid = data.users;` But you also overwrite the localstorage value each iteration

Comment: i mean this loop (sorry for the tons of code i put i wanted to show you all)  for(i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++){
                            console.log(tabuser[i].id);
                            displayfilter
                                .user(token,tabuser[i].id)
                                .then(function(data){

                                    console.log(data.tickets.length);
                                    $scope.numtickets = data.tickets;
                                })

Comment: you should attach numtickets directly to each user object and then use `user.numtickets` the same way you use `user.name`

Comment: just as a start, you have `</a></li>`, but there's no `<a>`.

Comment: and because i need to do 2 requests to display the number of tickets, it is even more complicated

Comment: you'll need to do what Vladimir said.

Comment: i would like to do what Vladimir says but if you see my code, request are not the same so variable are local so i have no choice to use for loop and no ng-repeat ( i loop in my controller and not on my view)